# Heroku / Rails 4 sqlite3 error on precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sqlite

My Heroku deploy is failing on the `Running: rake assets:precompile` step with the follow:

`` Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile. ``

My Gemfile has 'sqlite3' only in the development group, as you can see:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem "compass-rails", "~> 2.0.alpha.0"
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'devise'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'sendgrid'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem "cancan", :git => "git://github.com/ryanb/cancan.git", :branch => "2.0"
gem 'roadie', '2.4.2'

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', :platforms=>[:mri_19, :mri_20, :rbx]
  gem 'guard-bundler'
  gem 'guard-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-livereload'
  gem 'html2haml'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rails_layout'
  gem 'rb-fchange', :require=>false
  gem 'rb-fsevent', :require=>false
  gem 'rb-inotify', :require=>false
  gem 'debugger'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'zeus'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '1.0.1'
  gem 'email_spec'
end

group :production do
  gem 'unicorn'
  gem 'passenger'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Additionally, I am using the `rails_12factor` gem and `user-env-compile` thing... neither helped with the error. I've also added RACK_ENV=production and RAILS_ENV=production config vars to the Heroku environment, to be safe.

Seems like it Heroku is firing up the development environment when precompiling. Any ideas why?

Comment: can you output your database.yml file?

Comment: It is the default one generated by Rails. It is ignored by Git (and therefor Heroku) anyway, so I don't think it'd be relevant. Unless you know something I don't :)

Answer (score 2):

On Heroku, I've never gotten away without having `pg` in my production group.

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Assuming you're using that database in prod, of course.